# Thrust Complex Transform of 3 different size vectors

Tags: cuda, thrust

Hello I have this loop in C+, and I was trying to convert it to thrust but without getting the same results...
Any ideas?
thank you

**C++ Code**

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
    for (j=0;j<n;j++) 
      values[i]=values[i]+(binv[i*n+j]*d[j]);
```

**Thrust Code**

```
thrust::fill(values.begin(), values.end(), 0);
thrust::transform(make_zip_iterator(make_tuple(
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(values.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), IndexDivFunctor(n))),
                binv.begin(),
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), IndexModFunctor(n))))),
                make_zip_iterator(make_tuple(
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(values.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), IndexDivFunctor(n))) + n,
                binv.end(),
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), IndexModFunctor(n))) + n)),
                thrust::make_permutation_iterator(values.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), IndexDivFunctor(n))),
                function1()
                );
```

**Thrust Functions**

```
struct IndexDivFunctor: thrust::unary_function<int, int>
{
  int n;

  IndexDivFunctor(int n_) : n(n_) {}

  __host__ __device__
  int operator()(int idx)
  {
    return idx / n;
  }
};

struct IndexModFunctor: thrust::unary_function<int, int>
{
  int n;

  IndexModFunctor(int n_) : n(n_) {}

  __host__ __device__
  int operator()(int idx)
  {
    return idx % n;
  }
};


struct function1
{
  template <typename Tuple>
  __host__ __device__
  double operator()(Tuple v)
  {
    return thrust::get<0>(v) + thrust::get<1>(v) * thrust::get<2>(v);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, some general comments. Your loop

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
    for (j=0;j<n;j++) 
      v[i]=v[i]+(B[i*n+j]*d[j]);
```

is the equivalent of the standard [BLAS gemv](http://www.netlib.org/atlas/developer/atlas_contrib/node38.html) operation

[image]

where the matrix is stored in row major order. The optimal way to do this on the device would be using CUBLAS, not something constructed out of thrust primitives.

Having said that, there is absolutely no way the thrust code you posted is ever going to do what your serial code does. The errors you are seeing are not as a result of floating point associativity. Fundamentally `thrust::transform` applies the functor supplied to every element of the input iterator and stores the result on the output iterator. To yield the same result as the loop you posted, the `thrust::transform` call would need to perform (n*n) operations of the fmad functor you posted. Clearly it does not. Further, there is no guarantee that `thrust::transform` would perform the summation/reduction operation in a fashion that would be safe from memory races.

The correct solution is probably going to be something like:

1. Use thrust::transform to compute the (n*n) products of the elements of **B** and **d**
2. Use thrust::reduce_by_key to reduce the products into partial sums, yielding **Bd**
3. Use thrust::transform to add the resulting matrix-vector product to **v** to yield the final result.

In code, firstly define a functor like this:

```
struct functor
{
  template <typename Tuple>
  __host__ __device__
  double operator()(Tuple v)
  {
    return thrust::get<0>(v) * thrust::get<1>(v);
  }
};
```

Then do the following to compute the matrix-vector multiplication

```
  typedef thrust::device_vector<int> iVec;
  typedef thrust::device_vector<double> dVec;

  typedef thrust::counting_iterator<int> countIt;
  typedef thrust::transform_iterator<IndexDivFunctor, countIt> columnIt;
  typedef thrust::transform_iterator<IndexModFunctor, countIt> rowIt;

  // Assuming the following allocations on the device
  dVec B(n*n), v(n), d(n);

  // transformation iterators mapping to vector rows and columns
  columnIt cv_begin = thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), IndexDivFunctor(n));
  columnIt cv_end   = cv_begin + (n*n);

  rowIt rv_begin = thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), IndexModFunctor(n));
  rowIt rv_end   = rv_begin + (n*n);

  dVec temp(n*n);
  thrust::transform(make_zip_iterator(
                      make_tuple(
                        B.begin(),
                        thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d.begin(),rv_begin) ) ),
                    make_zip_iterator(
                      make_tuple(
                        B.end(),
                        thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d.end(),rv_end) ) ),
                    temp.begin(),
                    functor());

  iVec outkey(n);
  dVec Bd(n);
  thrust::reduce_by_key(cv_begin, cv_end, temp.begin(), outkey.begin(), Bd.begin());
  thrust::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), Bd.begin(), v.begin(), thrust::plus<double>());
```

Of course, this is a terribly inefficient way to do the computation compared to using a purpose designed matrix-vector multiplication code like `dgemv` from CUBLAS.

Answer (score 0):

How much your results differ? Is it a completely different answer, or differs only on the last digits? Is the loop executed only once, or is it some kind of iterative process?

Floating point operations, especially those that repetedly add up or multiply certain values, are *not* associative, because of precision issues. Moreover, if you use fast-math optimisations, the operations may not be IEEE compilant.

For starters, check out this wikipedia section on floating-point numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem is not with the floating points its totally different although i run it only once. Why do you think its right?

Comment: I blame the precision, because - in my experience - this is the most common source of differences. Of course, unless there is some straightforward bug, which I don't see in your code. How do you know for certain, problem is not there? How big are the differences? What kind of GPU you are running it on?

Comment: I m running on a gtx 460 with the arch20 and the vectors are doubles. could it be that the values vector writes to itself?

Comment: If there are doubles on the host and on device, it should not be a problem. Still would like to know the size of the differences between normal code and the transformed one. Is it completely different or differ by some smaller amount?